How do I move multiple Oracle objects to another user schema with PL/SQL?
I have an Oracle 12.1 dev database with a bunch (300+) of tables, views, sequences, procedures and functions.  Some are named with _BAK (sometimes dates), as the app was being tested and developed.  These don't belong in my export to my production db (AWS RDS Oracle 20.1).  It's not practical to come up with the proper export script for datapump or expdp to exclude so many objects.
I want to move them to other user schemas in the dev database, so we still have them for reference.  I would just drop them but other developers don't want to kill their darlings.
Then I can export only the user schemas with the desired objects.
SQL Developer will not all me to drag them from 1 user schema to another.
It seems the most practical would be a PL/SQL function or functions to move the objects to other users, then drop the originals.  I can start hacking something together but I was hoping there was something in the ballpark at stackoverflow.com, but I have not found it.
My thought is to have a function that has these parameters:  from_user, to_user, object_name.  It does not have to be perfect, 80/20 rule here.
If I make any reasonable progress, I will post my results as an answer to my own question.
Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.  Recommendations of a tool would be welcome.

A long time ago I used this tool from Dietmar Aust to export all object definitions to the file system. However, imo, this is solving a problem that shouldn't exist. The code should be stored and versioned in a repo.

@Koen Lostrie - I agree.  But in this case I am inheriting an environment where there was only 1 developer and he did not setup any source code control.  My first step is to attempt to reduce the clutter of objects, tables, views, sequences, procedures and functions. Then I will setup a repo.  I don't want to create the master branch with objects that are never used.

I feel your pain - good luck :)

Does this answer do what you want?

@KevinSeymour - No, but thanks.  Using datapump is great for exporting everything, but it does not cleanly move 1 object at a time to another user schema.
